# Kafka connector logs

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, connector

I am working on kafka connectors and by time my connectors are increasing. So my log file is getting really messy, I was wondering if it is possible to have separate log file for each connector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use grep command to view only the required logs.

command: `tail /var/log/kafka/connect.log  -f | grep -n 'phrase to search'`

your path for log file could be different.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are trying to achieve is not possible as of current Kafka-connect implementation. But there is a KIP under discussion which may help you when it's accepted and implemented. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-449%3A+Add+connector+contexts+to+Connect+worker+logs